# Issue with MatDialog and Iframe

Tags: html, angular, iframe, angular-material

I have some issues working with Angular material MatDialog and an Iframe which is Libcast. When I am changing the size of the window or set the video as fullscreen, there are different issues I met. 
On Chrome: the video starts over and I can see that's the window is refresh.
On Modzilla: the video crash when I turn on full screen and it goes back to the no-fullscreenpage.

I have tried to add directly the Iframe in the MatDialog with the developper tool and I don't meet any issues, it's working perfectly.

```js
  private openLibcastResource(resource: Resource) {
    this.dialog.open(VideoComponent, {
      data: {url: resource.sourceInfo.src},
    });
  }
```

```js
@Component({
             selector: 'app-video',
             templateUrl: './video.component.html',
           })
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
              public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<VideoComponent>,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public videoUrl() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.data.url);
  }
}
```

```html
  <iframe [src]="videoUrl()" class="libcast_player" width="560" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;"></iframe>
```

Do you have any ideas of what's happening ?

Comment: Post your code thats causing the issue, it'll assist people in being able to help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getUrl() was called each time I was modifing the window size. So the Video was reset and that's why it was crashing for fullscreen also.